# Basic Static-to-Static Rewrite (or Redirect) via htaccess or httpd.conf

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting, rewritemap

We are moving from one site language/CMS (coldfusion/custom) to another (PHP/Drupal) and need to have some of our old pages redirected to new ones. I have access to both the .htaccess and httpd.conf (and apache2.conf) as this is a vps on Linode.

Most of them cannot be done via regular expression (they contain GUIDs in the URL) and we're ok writing static redirects.

Here's an example:

```
  RewriteRule /show.cfm/FG3f4-30F1G/ http://www.mysite.com/john-smith [R=301]
```

that's it...I've tried the syntax with the starting caret ^, ending dollar sign, none of it seems to work.

I may have a misunderstanding as to what role the RewriteCond plays -- there are other lines already in the .htaccess.

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Do I need to re-declare the RewriteCond once the RewriteRule is specified?

Also -- Ideally, to preserve cleanliness in the .htaccess, I would like to use a RewriteMap, where I can specify one text file and just have two tab-delimited columns of "old url | new url"...but I can't get that to work either (if it's even appropriate to use).

Any ideas would be MOST welcome...

Answer (score 0):

For your first static example you would be better off using the Redirect directive rather than mod_rewrites RedirectRule.

A RewriteCond only applies to the RewriteRule that directly follows it. So in your OP the conds states if the requested URI is not a real file or directoruy and it's not the favicon, then redirect it to index.php

With regards to you attempting it with the carat and it not working, this is likely a paths issue and the exact solution depends on whether the RewriteRule is located in the httpd.conf file or in the .htaccess. As a generally rules patterns you are matching in httpd.conf will be preceeded by a forward slash, wheras ones you are matching against in a .htaccess file will not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply; however, using a Redirect (or RedirectMatch) will append the old string to the new string, thus causing a loop

For example:

Redirect permanent /index2.html /index1.html

becomes:

http://www.mysite.com/index.html?q=index2.html

Comment: If that is happening it has nothing to do with the Redirect directive itself and something else is coming into play. Redirect 301 /foo.php /bar.php will take a request for foo.php and will redirect to (plain old) bar.php

Comment: `mod_alias` works after `mod_rewrite`, and though the rewritten URL has not be passed through to `mod_alias`, for unintended reasons the modified query string (as per `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]`) gets appended to the URL that `Redirect` sends back to the client to change to.

Comment: Ahh, I figured it was something like that, but didn't realise mod_rewrite was always executed first.

Answer (score 0):

As [Cags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477177/basic-static-to-static-rewrite-or-redirect-via-htaccess-or-httpd-conf/3477247#3477247) pointed out, if you're defining your rules in your `.htaccess` file, you need to make sure that the paths do not contain a leading slash. Additionally, you likely need to make sure to use the `L` flag, as well as position the redirect rules above the WordPress rewrite section, since both of these things will likely end up causing a conflict otherwise.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^/?show.cfm/FG3f4-30F1G/$ http://www.mysite.com/john-smith [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

If you want to use a `RewriteMap`, you'll need to define it in your server or virtual server configuration. Normally this is a problem for most people, but since you've indicated that you're on a VPS, I would assume you have the necessary access. Note that it would also be beneficial, for efficiency reasons, to put all of your `mod_rewrite` directives there, since the `.htaccess` has to be parsed for each request (but the server configuration is only processed at startup).

Defining a server map would look like this in `httpd.conf` (or equivalent):

```
RewriteMap redirect-map txt:/full/path/to/file/pathmap.txt
```

You would then modify your rule accordingly:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(show\.cfm/[A-Za-z0-9-]+/)$ http://www.example.com/${redirect-map:$1} [R=301,L]
```

...with `pathmap.txt` looking something like:

```
# Input                Replacement
show.cfm/FG3f4-30F1G/  john-smith
show.cfm/ABC12-40000/  jane-doe
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on "Linode" VPS, you also need to update your Virtual Host config file, to "AllowOverride All" string from "AllowOverride None".

Typically, on LInode, this config file is in the "/etc/apache2/sites-enabled" directory. Without changing files in this directory, Rewrite Engine on Linode will not work.